# Nodejs while loop doesnt work

Tags: node.js

```
 repeat(1000, function() {  
        console.log("REPEAT");
        var i = 1;
        var max = 1;
        var mS = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/XXX/Temp/MS.ini', 'utf-8'));
        var array = new Array();
        while(i<=max){
            if(typeof mS[i] != 'undefined'){
                if(mS[i]['10'] == true){
                    array.push(i);
                    console.log(array);
                }else{
                    console.log("ERROR");
                }
                i++;
                max++;
            }else{ //if undefined
                if(mS[i+1] == 'undefined' && mS[i+2] == 'undefined') i++;
                else{ i++; max++; }
            }
        }//while
    });
```

It works without repeat function. (waitjs module) 
Also repeat works without while loop.
I am trying to become reconciled to node.js (single thread). But i do not know, where is the mistake?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
var max = 1;
while(i<=max){
```

This condition is valid only once.

Update (due to @user949300 comments):

How many times your loop executes depends on your ini file. I recommend you to step into your code with a [debugger](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

Comment: He does increment i++ and max++ _most of the time_ in the inner code, but there is one path where he only increments i++.

Comment: You are right. Although this may guide him to the reason. I'll update my answer.

Comment: while loop work clearly without repeat function. It checks in .ini file if there is a title, ill continue (increase max). I dont know how many title in .ini file. But its not about while loop

Comment: I don't know what `ini.parse` does or where it comes from, but it doesn't get "reset" like all the local vars.  Is it possible that it behaves differently the 2nd (and subsequent) times in the repeat?